# Python find the multiple sets based on condition from dataframe and read the first and line from every set

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file (2 different sample)-

Sample-1 -

```
   Date-Time              Func    Byte
2023/01/01 16:45:13       APP      0 
2023/01/01 16:57:08       APP      1  
2023/01/01 17:10:44       APP      5 
2023/01/01 17:11:04       APP      0  
2023/01/01 17:12:24       APP      0 
2023/01/01 17:15:27       APP      4
2023/01/01 17:16:08       APP      4
```

Sample-2 -

```
   Date-Time              Func    Byte
2023/01/01 16:45:13       APP      4 
2023/01/01 16:57:08       APP      1  
2023/01/01 17:10:44       APP      5 
2023/01/01 17:11:04       APP      0  
2023/01/01 17:12:24       APP      0 
2023/01/01 17:15:27       APP      4
2023/01/01 17:16:08       APP      4 
2023/01/01 17:16:20       APP      0
```

I want to get the start_time(when Byte value start as non-zero) and end time(when Byte value end as non-zero),
also leave the end time as empty if it's last line of the file-

Output from Sample 1 -

```
Date/Time(Start)         Func         Date/Time(Start)
2023/01/01 16:57:08      APP         2023/01/01 17:10:44
2023/01/01 17:15:27      APP
```

Output from Sample 2 -

```
Date/Time(Start)         Func         Date/Time(Start)
2023/01/01 16:45:13      APP         2023/01/01 17:10:44
2023/01/01 17:15:27      APP         2023/01/01 17:16:08
```

Comment: Whats happens if only one row group? Like changed second df last 3 values to `0,4,0` ?

Comment: Also `APP` is used for groups?

Comment: @jezrael if only one row group in that case start and end date will be the same. 'APP' is some other column but will have same value always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
# is Byte 0?
m = df['Byte'].eq(0)
# form groups of the values following a 0
group = m.cumsum()
# identify first non-0 of each group
m2 = ~group.mask(m).duplicated(keep='first').mask(m, True)

# assign last value and filter
out = df[m2].assign(**{'Date/Time(End)':
                       df['Date-Time']
                       .mask(group.duplicated(keep='last')
                             |(df.index==df.index[-1]) # ignore last row
                            ).bfill()
                      })
```

Output:

```
# first example
            Date-Time Func  Byte      Date/Time(End)
1 2023-01-01 16:57:08  APP     1 2023-01-01 17:10:44
5 2023-01-01 17:15:27  APP     4                 NaT

# second example
            Date-Time Func  Byte      Date/Time(End)
0 2023-01-01 16:45:13  APP     4 2023-01-01 17:10:44
5 2023-01-01 17:15:27  APP     4 2023-01-01 17:16:08
```

Intermediates:

*The rows with `*` are the final rows in the output.*

```
            Date-Time Func  Byte      m  group     m2               bfill
0 2023-01-01 16:45:13  APP     0   True      1  False 2023-01-01 17:10:44
1 2023-01-01 16:57:08  APP     1  False      1   True 2023-01-01 17:10:44 *
2 2023-01-01 17:10:44  APP     5  False      1  False 2023-01-01 17:10:44
3 2023-01-01 17:11:04  APP     0   True      2  False 2023-01-01 17:11:04
4 2023-01-01 17:12:24  APP     0   True      3  False                 NaT
5 2023-01-01 17:15:27  APP     4  False      3   True                 NaT *
6 2023-01-01 17:16:08  APP     4  False      3  False                 NaT
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @mozway.. it's working as expected. Cheers..!

Answer (score 1):

First filter out non `0` values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and by consecutive non `0` values by cumulative sums by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) create groups, so possible aggreagate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) `first` and `last` value of datetime and index column used for test last value:

```
#create default index if necessary
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

m = df['Byte'].eq(0)

out = (df.reset_index()[~m]
        .groupby([m.cumsum(), 'Func'])
        .agg(**{'Date/Time(Start)':('Date-Time', 'first'),
                'Date/Time(End)':('Date-Time', 'last'),
                'last':('index','last')})
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index())

out.loc[out.pop('last').eq(df.index[-1]), 'Date/Time(End)'] = ''
```

---

```
print (out)
  Func     Date/Time(Start)       Date/Time(End)
0  APP  2023/01/01 16:57:08  2023/01/01 17:10:44
1  APP  2023/01/01 17:15:27                     

print (out)
              Date/Time(Start)       Date/Time(End)
Byte Func                                          
0    APP   2023/01/01 16:45:13  2023/01/01 17:10:44
2    APP   2023/01/01 17:15:27  2023/01/01 17:16:08
```

If need processing solution per groups by `Func` column:

```
print (df)
              Date-Time  Func  Byte
0   2023/01/01 16:45:13   APP     0
1   2023/01/01 16:57:08   APP     1
2   2023/01/01 17:10:44   APP     5
3   2023/01/01 17:11:04   APP     0
4   2023/01/01 17:12:24   APP     0
5   2023/01/01 17:15:27   APP     4
6   2023/01/01 17:16:08   APP     4
7   2023/01/01 16:45:13  APP1     4
8   2023/01/01 16:57:08  APP1     1
9   2023/01/01 17:10:44  APP1     5
10  2023/01/01 17:11:04  APP1     0
11  2023/01/01 17:12:24  APP1     0
12  2023/01/01 17:15:27  APP1     4
13  2023/01/01 17:16:08  APP1     4
14  2023/01/01 17:16:20  APP1     0
```

---

```
m = df['Byte'].eq(0)

df1 = df.reset_index()
out = (df1[~m]
        .groupby([m.cumsum(), 'Func'])
        .agg(**{'Date/Time(Start)':('Date-Time', 'first'),
                'Date/Time(End)':('Date-Time', 'last'),
                'last':('index','last')})
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index())

last = df1.groupby('Func')['index'].last()
out.loc[out.pop('last').isin(last), 'Date/Time(End)'] = ''
print (out)
   Func     Date/Time(Start)       Date/Time(End)
0   APP  2023/01/01 16:57:08  2023/01/01 17:10:44
1   APP  2023/01/01 17:15:27                     
2  APP1  2023/01/01 16:45:13  2023/01/01 17:10:44
3  APP1  2023/01/01 17:15:27  2023/01/01 17:16:08
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @jezrael.. it's working as expected. Cheers..!